"Not all parameters were used in the SQL statement" when inserting values from file to database
I get an error when trying to insert into the database table with the following code
import mysql.connector
import re

mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
  host="",
  user="",
  password="",
  database ="db"
)
mycursor = mydb.cursor()

sql = "INSERT INTO characters (url, name, disambiguation) VALUES (%s, %s, %s)"
val = []
with open("text.txt","r",encoding="utf-8") as f:
    for line in f.readlines():
      x = re.findall(r'"(.*?)"', line)
      x= x[::-1]
      x.append("")
      val.append(x)

mycursor.executemany("INSERT INTO characters (name, url, disambiguation) VALUES (%s, %s, %s)", val)
mydb.commit()

The contents of val looks like this:
[["'Lectron (Earth-12772)", '/wiki/%27Lectron_(Earth-12772)', ''], ["'Selka (Earth-928)", '/wiki/%27Selka_(Earth-928)', ''], ["'Spinner (Earth-616)", '/wiki/%27Spinner_(Earth-616)', ''],...]

While the query DESCRIBE TABLE returns this:
('name', 'varchar(255)', 'YES', '', None, '')
('url', 'varchar(255)', 'YES', '', None, '')
('disambiguation', 'varchar(255)', 'YES', '', None, '')

If there's only three parameters and I'm passing all three in I don't know why I'm receiving the error.

most likely that one of the array elements has only two or less values, run through the array and find them

Thanks for the comment, what happened was that the text file that the code is reading from to populate the array was cleaned up with some find and replace beforehand but on one singular line the find and replace was ignored and added extra value to the array. I fixed that and then there was no problem

Please add your solution as an answer, not as part of the question.

One of the sub-arrays passed into val was incorrectly formatted in the original text file which meant that the sub-array had 4 values instead of the intended 3.I fixed the text file and everything worked from there.
